# Simplify syntax when working with XML namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

In a simple **.vbproj** file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
</Project>
```

I would like to store a collection of `<PropertyGroup>` elements. The problem I found is the need to specify the (long) namespace everytime that I call **`XDocument.Element()`** or **`XDocument.Elements()`** functions:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("My project.vbproj");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text, LoadOptions.None);

IEnumerable<XElement> propGroups = 
    doc.Element("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}Project").
        Elements("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}PropertyGroup");
```

I'm pretty sure should exists a better friendly syntax to simplify the code above, maybe to call just once **`XDocument.Elements()`** instead of **`XDocument.Element()`**, or maybe to avoid specifying the namespace (or mroe than once) with a proper XPath and using **`XDocument.XPathSelectElements()`** instead, however, seems that I cannot use XPATH v2.0 to ignore the namespace like `//*:Project/PropertyGroup` (or maybe my syntax is wrong?).

Someone could explain me how can I refactor it?.

Note that the purpose is to modify some properties of the Xml then save the changes in the file, not just to get the data that is inside the Xml (if that matters for a solution).

Comment: Have you looked at [XNamespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Tim Thanks for the reference, from what I see the solution shown in the MSDN code examples are doing the same as I did, but just using a var to reference the namespace name. To be honest I expect other kind of proper solution than what MSDN shown. Because in essence it shows the same, a namespace string that need to be specified/concatenated all the time.

Comment: How about [XName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname(v=vs.110).aspx)?  It has properties for the local name (without the namespace), as well as the namespace and the URI of the associated XNamespace.

Comment: I usually use this : IEnumerable<XElement> propGroups = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "PropertyGroup");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not particularly interested in explicitly identifying that `Project` is the direct parent of `PropertyGroup`, you can instead use `Descendants` to find all `PropertyGroup` elements no matter where they appear in the document:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
var propGroups = doc.Descendants(ns + "PropertyGroup");
```

The intention of the API was to the use the `+` operator to combine a namespace with a local name to avoid the verbosity of including it for each name. There's no simple way of avoiding using the namespace if you want to identify the element using it.  Filtering by local name is far more verbose than this.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the namespace string into a variable and use it this way:

```
XNamespace yourns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

IEnumerable<XElement> propGroups = 
    doc.Element(yourns + "Project").
        Elements(yourns + "PropertyGroup");
```

I think it is a more readable and re-usable solution.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the need of specifying the namespace two times still exists in the example you gave like in the original code I provided, just in a different way. To be honest I missed the fact of putting the string into a var when publishing the code in the question, but I expect other kind of solution that doesn't implies doing that.

Comment: You should drop the `{}` from the namespace as this isn't part of it.

Comment: You are right! I made a bad copy and paste. I am sorry. I edited the answer. Thanks @CharlesMager.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered the proper usage of XPath v1.0, this way totally avoids writting the intermediary namespace:

```
Dim propGroups As IEnumerable(Of XElement) =
    doc.XPathSelectElements("//*[local-name()='Project']//*[local-name()='PropertyGroup']")
```

However, in case of a large hierarchy the repeated string "`//*[local-name()=`" will cause more or less the same annonying syntax than specifying all the time the namespace. Anyways I preffer XPath usage than a *LINQ-to-Objects* query.

I will not accept my own answer because I'm not totally sure whether the XPath syntax is as simplified as it could be.

Also in XPath v2.0 will be much more simplified, however, seems that .NET doesn't support it (or maybe I used a wrong syntax when testing).